# The expression which the key /tikz/graphs/m is supposed to be an abbreviation of, isn't equivalent to it

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-graphs

The section "Graph `subgraph I_nm`" on pp. 299-300 of the TikZ & PGF manual for version 3.0.1a states (on p. 300) that the key `/tikz/graphs/m=<number>` is an abbreviation for `W={1,...,<number>}, name shore W={name=W}`, and the following example is given (I've added the first three lines and the last line for completeness).

```
\input tikz
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs.standard}
\tikz \graph {
    subgraph I_nm [n=3, m=4];

    V 1 -- { W 2, W 3 };
    V 2 -- { W 1, W 3 };
    V 3 -- { W 1, W 4 };
};
\end
```

with the resulting graph

[image: I_mn graph]

But when I replaced "`m=4`" with "`W={1,...,4},name shore W={name=W}`", the following graph was produced. Why?

[image: Substituting the definition of m=4]

Comment: look for the definition `m/.style` or `m/.code` in the TikZ `graphs` source file. It seems like it is doing other things too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a typo in the documentation. It later on says also that `name shore W` is style that should be set. This here works as expected:

```
\input tikz
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs.standard}
\tikz \graph {
    subgraph I_nm [n=3, W={1,...,4},name shore W/.style={name=W}];

    V 1 -- { W 2, W 3 };
    V 2 -- { W 1, W 3 };
    V 3 -- { W 1, W 4 };
};
\end
```

[image]